# Using Ajax to suggest unavaliable number using current list numbers

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery

is it possible to using ajax with PHP/SQL to suggest the next avaliable number for a user based on the current numbers in the list? this is to avoid duplication.

I have a form/table https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYhSG.png and in this table I have for an example departments and a list(the numbers in the list needs to be unqiue). because of the way the system is disigned, users had to manually rearrange the numbers if they wanted to the same number in another department. for an example number "4" can only be used once, this example applies to any other numbers.

The numbers in those `list` are all avaliable in the database, what this means is that I have a select statement and i echo `$list` to redender those `list` you show in the image.

Tp avoid users having to manally tryping those numbers especially if the list is up to 100 or more. I basically want to use ajax to `first` check if the number in the list is already in used and if `yes` then `suggest` a number to them.

Can this be done? If so please show me an example.

Thanks for your time.

p.s.

i missed out an information piece of information they is another column called `values

```
tablename:  check


values          type               list
cars             1                   2
cars             1                   4
cars             1                   3
bicycle          1                   2
bicycle          1                   3
bicycle          1                   4
```

the numbers in the `list` can be used again if the `values` is different so basically the `list` needs to be unique to the `values` is it in.

Answer (score 0):

If the column list needs to be unique and automatically increment, you should be using MySQL's [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

This will automatically populate the column with the next available number on row creation.

Comment: @David_Houde, sorry i missed out an important piece of details. 

please look at the updated question

Comment: @David_Houde please look at the new image link. Thanks